# Remove .php extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I have two pieces of code that removes the .php extension.

**Solution 1:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

---

`directory` is a directory

`page` is a page

***problem with solution 1:***

if you go to domain.com/directory, it is supposed to show domain.com/directory/index.php but the index.php does not appear and it just shows a 404 error page.

***problem with solution 2:***

if you go to domain.com/directory/page/haha-lol-blah-blah, the page domain.com/directory/page shows up, no matter what is after the page.

---

**is there a solution for both problems?**

here is what i need:

```
domain.com/directory -> shows the page: domain.com/directory/index.php
domain.com/directory/page -> shows the page: domain.com/directory/page.php
domain.com/directory/page/haha-lol-blah-blah -> invalid page (404)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working now with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
#incoming request neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$ $1.php [L]
```